# How can I display my data dynamically onclick event in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a movies app with React and Redux, in each movie card I have some information about the movie like the title, image, and a button(buy a ticket). The idea is when I click on the button of each card I want to get the same image and title of the card and display it on the same page on another card that going to pop up so the user can choose the quantity and continue.

How can I get the data from the movie card onclick and transform it to another card as a pop-up?

what do you think

**Single movie card Component**

```
const SingleMovieCard = ({ id, title, poster_path, overview, toggleHandler }) => {
    const [selected, isSelected] = useState(null);

    return (
        <article key={id} className="card">
            <div key={id} onMouseEnter={() => isSelected(id)} onMouseLeave={() => isSelected(null)}>
                <img src={`${ImgPath}` + poster_path} alt={title} className="image" />
                {selected === id && <video src="./Trailers/SpaceJam.mp4" autoPlay={true} loop muted />}
            </div>
            <div className="body-card">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <p>{`${overview.substring(0, 200)}...`}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="services">
                <FiShare2 className="icon" />
                <FiHeart className="icon" />
                <div className="btn-icon-container">
                    <BiShoppingBag className="btn-icon" />
                    <button onClick={() => toggleHandler()}>Buy Ticket</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    )
}


export default SingleMovieCard;
```

***Pop-up movie card***

```
const PopUpMovie = ({showClass, toggleHandler}) => {

    const moviesList = useSelector((state)=> state.allMovies.movies);
    return (
    <div className={`pop-up-container ${showClass}`}>
       <nav className="pop-up">
           <GrClose className="pop-up-close" onClick={()=> toggleHandler()}/>
           <div className="product-details">
               <div className="img-container">
                   <img src="./Pictures/FreeGuy.jpg" alt="FreeGuy" />
               </div>
               <div className="product info">
                   <h1 className="title">Free Guy movie</h1>
                   <div className="quantity">
                       <h4>Quantity</h4>
                       <span>4</span>
                   </div>
                   <h5 className="prix">11$</h5>
                   <button className="btn-checkout">Continue to checkout</button> 
               </div>
           </div>
       </nav>}
    </div>
    )
}

export default PopUpMovie;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use *Modal* from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/)

Example:

```
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
const PopUpMovie = ({ showClass, toggleHandler }) => {

const modalContent = (
    <div className={`pop-up-container ${showClass}`}>
        <nav className="pop-up">
            <GrClose className="pop-up-close" onClick={() => toggleHandler()} />
            <div className="product-details">
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img src="./Pictures/FreeGuy.jpg" alt="FreeGuy" />
                </div>
                <div className="product info">
                    <h1 className="title">Free Guy movie</h1>
                    <div className="quantity">
                        <h4>Quantity</h4>
                        <span>4</span>
                    </div>
                    <h5 className="prix">11$</h5>
                    <button className="btn-checkout">Continue to checkout</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
)

const moviesList = useSelector((state) => state.allMovies.movies);
return (
    <Modal
        id="order-modal-close"
        backdrop="static"
        show={showClass}
        size={"md"}
        dialogClassName="modal-90w"
        onHide={toggleHandler}
    >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Movie</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body >{modalContent}</Modal.Body>
        {modalFooter}
    </Modal>
)
}
```